# Chart.js - how to set a margin for axes min\max and time axis label separation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a **Chart.js 2.9.4** chart that has `time` X-axis (displays a date). Sample code that I use:

```js
var data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: "dataset1",
    lineTension: 0,  
    fill: false,  
    backgroundColor: '#43dea6',
    borderColor: '#43dea6',
    data: [{t:"2021-03-30T00:00:00",y:6},{t:"2021-04-01T00:00:00",y:3},{t:"2021-04-05T00:00:00",y:4},{t:"2021-04-12T00:00:00",y:7},{t:"2021-04-19T00:00:00",y:6},{t:"2021-04-26T00:00:00",y:8},{t:"2021-05-04T00:00:00",y:10},{t:"2021-05-11T00:00:00",y:10},{t:"2021-06-09T00:00:00",y:2},{t:"2021-06-16T00:00:00",y:3},{t:"2021-06-23T00:00:00",y:4}]
  },
  {
    label: "dataset2",
    lineTension: 0,  
    fill: false,  
    backgroundColor: '#e44269',
    borderColor: '#e44269',
    data: [{t:"2021-03-30T00:00:00",y:0},{t:"2021-04-01T00:00:00",y:3},{t:"2021-04-05T00:00:00",y:1},{t:"2021-04-12T00:00:00",y:1},{t:"2021-04-19T00:00:00",y:1},{t:"2021-04-26T00:00:00",y:0},{t:"2021-05-04T00:00:00",y:0},{t:"2021-05-11T00:00:00",y:0},{t:"2021-06-09T00:00:00",y:4},{t:"2021-06-16T00:00:00",y:3},{t:"2021-06-23T00:00:00",y:2}]
  }]
};

var options = {
    animation: false,    
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                            unit: 'day',
                tooltipFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
                displayFormats: {
                    day: 'DD.MM.YY'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<div id="chartDiv"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And I need 3 things:

1. Set an **automatic** 5% margin for axes min\max. I know that I can calculate min\max values by myself and set them via `ticks.min\ticks.max` options, but it's not so easy and obvoius for `time` X-axis.
2. Ensure that each point will definitelly have corresponding tick and label on X-axis.
3. Set an **automatic** X-axis label separation (for my taste Chart.js draws them too close for each other).

Many charting libraries have axis margin options (in pixels or percents of axis full length), "labels at points" and label separation options (in pixels or percents of axis label width) - maybe Chart.js also has..

**Here what I have now:**

[image: Here what I have now]

**Here what I need:**

[image: Here what I need]

P. S. If some of that features are possible only in **Chart.js 3.x** - no problem, I can upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem afaik there is no other solution as to calculate it yourself, in V3 they added a `grace` property ([docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#grace)) which does this but it only applies to linear axis.

For your second problem you can use the tick callback. You get the value and then you can check your data source if it has a point matched to it, if so you return it again, if not you can return an empty string. See this example for more info: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/scale-options/ticks.html

For your third problem you can increase the `autoSkipPadding` ([docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/))

Comment: Looks like you answer is double-sized :) Thank you.

Comment: Forgive me if it's not entirely clear, can't add inline examples since I'm on Holliday so no pc :)

Comment: Your answer is entirely understandable, thank you. I've just removed text duplication and added doc links to it. If no better solutions will be provided - I'll use this one.